IAT hook is not working with notepad.exe on Windows 10
When I inject this DLL via the conventional LoadLibrary method, the DLL is injected and when I attach it notepad.exe and run it in a debugger, it seems to work (in terms of.. I don't get errors and it does execute each line of code).
However, when I type some characters in notepad or save the file to disk, it still calls the original WriteFile function, while it should call my custom WriteFile function.
When I type some characters in notepad and monitor the calls with APIMonitor, notepad does in fact call NtWriteFile directly (for each character I type) to save the data in a temporary file, but when I save it on disk it calls WriteFile.
Someone once said that possibly loaderlock occurs, is that the case? Although, I don't call one of these functions from DLL main?
*Note: for some reason, when I remove the fprintf statements, I get an error:

"Debug assertion failed"

#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>


    FILE* file_pointer;
    FILE* write_file;
    HMODULE array_modules[1024];
    DWORD number_bytes;
    DWORD WB = 0;
    WCHAR BUFFER[1024]; //Unicode characters
    int i;
    char BUFFER_OUTPUT[] = "test1"; //Unicode characters
    typedef int(WINAPI* Func_Pointer)(HANDLE, LPCVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPOVERLAPPED);
    Func_Pointer Original_VA_WriteFile = NULL;
    
    
    
    BOOL WINAPI WriteFile_HOOK(HANDLE hFile, LPCVOID lpBuffer,
        DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
    {
    
    
        fopen_s(&write_file, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputinjectedDLL7.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(write_file, "test");
        fclose(write_file);
        return Original_VA_WriteFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToWrite, lpNumberOfBytesWritten, lpOverlapped); 
    }
    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE Base_DLL_Address, DWORD Reason_CALL, LPVOID Reserved)
    {
        switch (Reason_CALL)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

            MessageBoxA(NULL, "OK", "01", MB_OK);
            Original_VA_WriteFile = WriteFile;
            DWORD PID = GetCurrentProcessId();
            HANDLE Handle_Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
            if (Handle_Process == NULL) {
                DWORD error = GetLastError();
                fprintf(file_pointer, "Handle not retrieved %s", error);
            }
            else {
                fopen_s(&file_pointer, "C:\\Users\\Mikail\\Documents\\outputinjectedDLL10.txt", "w+");
                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVA of WriteFile_HOOK is :%p", WriteFile_HOOK);
                char* ImageBase = NULL;
    
                if (EnumProcessModules(Handle_Process, array_modules, sizeof(array_modules), &number_bytes) != 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < (number_bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++) {
                        DWORD Module_LEN_string = GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle_Process, array_modules[i], BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER));
                        if (wcsstr(BUFFER, L"Notepad.exe") != NULL) {
                            ImageBase = array_modules[i];
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nImagebase: %p", ImageBase);
                            PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)ImageBase;
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\ndosHeader: %p", dosHeaders);
                            PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + dosHeaders->e_lfanew);
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nntHeader: %p", ntHeaders);
                            IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImportsDirectory_RVA = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
                            PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR Import_Directory = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(ImportsDirectory_RVA.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase);
                            fprintf(file_pointer, "\nImport Directory: %p", Import_Directory);
    
                            while (Import_Directory->Name != NULL)
                            {
                                char* Module_AA = (char*)(ImageBase + Import_Directory->Name);
    
                                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA OFT_value = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->OriginalFirstThunk; //RVA_OFT
                                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA PointerModule_AA_OFT = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->OriginalFirstThunk + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase; //VA_OFT
                                PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA PointerModule_AA_FT = (LPCSTR)Import_Directory->FirstThunk + (DWORD_PTR)ImageBase; //(R)VA_FT
    
                                if (strstr(Module_AA, "KERNEL32.dll") != NULL) {
                                    while (PointerModule_AA_FT->u1.Function != NULL) {

                                        PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA Win32_Function_AA_FT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)PointerModule_AA_FT->u1.Function; //AA WIN32 Function
                                        PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA Win32_Function_RVA_OFT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)PointerModule_AA_OFT->u1.Function; //RVA WIN32 Function
    
                                        PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + PointerModule_AA_OFT->u1.AddressOfData);

                                        if (strstr(functionName->Name, "WriteFile")) {
    

                                            DWORD OR_Access_Rights;
    
                                            int VirtualProtect_Memory = VirtualProtect(&Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function, sizeof(DWORD_PTR), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OR_Access_Rights);
                                            if (VirtualProtect_Memory == 0) {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVirtualProtectMemory FAILED");
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nVirtualProtectMemory SUCCEEDED: %d", VirtualProtect_Memory);
                                            }
    
                                            Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)WriteFile_HOOK;
                                            if (Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function == (DWORD_PTR)WriteFile_HOOK) {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nAddress stored in IAT %p", Win32_Function_AA_FT->u1.Function);
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nAddress of WriteFile_HOOK %p", WriteFile_HOOK);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                fprintf(file_pointer, "\nHOOK FAILED");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        PointerModule_AA_OFT++;
                                    }
                                }
                                Import_Directory++;
                            } 
                        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
                    }
                    return TRUE;
                }
                ;
            }
        }

    }


You only increment PointerModule_AA_OFT, but you have to increment PointerModule_AA_FT as well.
